# PHP HTTP Authentication Failing To Authenticate

Tags: php, javascript, html, authentication

I am creating a web application in PHP for a server that does not have SSL support. If you want to brag about how good SSL is for authentication, do it somewhere else. I am using HTTP Authentication with PHP and a bit of javascript. Here is the login form page:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css"/>
<script>
function getHTTPObject() {
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    try {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    return false;
}

function login(form, action)
{

    var http = getHTTPObject();
    var username = form.citizenid.value + "-username";
    var password = form.cikatid.value + form.redid.value + "-password";
    http.open("get", action, false, username, password);
    http.send("");
    if (http.status == 200) {
        document.location = action;
    } else {
        alert("Incorrect username and/or password.");
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<title>
Corstekistan - eVote
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/headevote.php";
?>
<hr/>
<span class="title">eVote - By The Republic of Corstekistan</span>
<p>eVote lets you participate in Corsteki elections and referendums online. To begin, please fill out the information below to prove that you are a citizen of The Republic of Corstekistan.</p>
<span style="text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto">
<form name="citizenproof" action="" method="get">
<fieldset style="width: 400px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto">
<legend>Provide Proof Of Citizenship</legend>
<noscript><span style="font-weight: bold;color: red">This webpage requires JavaScript to function. Please enable it or use a modern web browser.<br/></span></noscript>
<span style="font-weight: bold;color: red" id="err"></span>
Citizen ID: <input type="text" name="citizenid" required="true"/>
<br/>
CĪKAT ID: <input type="text" name="cikatid" required="true"/>
<br/>
Red ID: <input type="text" name="redid" required="true"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Sign In" onclick="login(this.form, '/evote/votesys')"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
<p>Don't know how to find the CĪKAT and Red IDs on your National ID Card? Click <a href="idguide.php">here</a></p>
</span>
```

Here is the protected page:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="eVote"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

When I click 'Sign On', it doesn't redirect me to the protected page, like it should. Instead a dialog box pops up asking me to authenticate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you setting the PHP_AUTH_USER variable? I don't see it...

Comment: You're all good to go, Corstekistan doesn't have hackers anyway. You're missing jQuery BTW ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using AJAX to perform this login ( It's Asynchronous ) . It means that it won't redirect you.

Comment: But doesn't the false parameter have it wait until a response is returned. And why does the dialog box asking me to input credentials when I already have?

Comment: @Ian It does but it doesn't help you do the authentication right. To do this you may have to redirect to another page (not AJAX) and then after the authentication is complete you can callback(redirect) to your current page.